# overloading operator+ char

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i try to make exercises and have a problem.

I do not know how to overload the operator+ for char;

The aim is to solve those equation:

```
cout<<"Please enter here a title: "<<endl;
cin>>s2;
s1="I am a " + s2;
```

The private part of the String class:

```
    private:
char * str; // pointer to string
int len; // length of string
static int num_strings; // number of objects
static const int CINLIM = 80;
```

i tried the following code, but it doesnt work:

```
    String operator+(const String &st1, const String &st2)
{ String sum;
    int len1=std::strlen(st1.str);
    int len2=std::strlen(st2.str);
    int lenges=len1+len2;
    sum.str=new char[lenges+1];

    char *a=st1.str;
    char *b=st2.str;

    while(*a++) {*a++;}
    while(*b++) {*a=*b;}

    sum.str=st1.str;

return sum.str;
}
```

Can someone give a tip?

P.S. The class String contains char * str and int len;

Comment: Neither of `"Hello"` or `"I am"` is a `String`, so of course `operator+` taking two `String`s cannot apply to them. More generally, you cannot overload operators acting on fundamental types alone (it would be a nightmare if you could include a header and end up with `2+2 != 4`). Anyway, what do you mean by "solve equations" here?

Comment: Please show the `String` class.

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded operators are NOT considered unless at least one operand has a class or enumeration type.  In the expression `"Hello" + "I am"`, the operands have types `const char[6]` and `const char[5]`, which can both decay to `const char*`, but since only builtin types are involved here, your custom `operator+` doesn't do anything.

You will need to explicitly tell the compiler to convert at least one operand to your `String` type, as in `String("Hello") + "I am"`.

(Or if you want to define a user-defined literal operator, you would be able to write that as something like `"Hello"_str + "I am"_str`.)

Comment: What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try something like this

std::string str = "str1" + std::string("str2");

Comment: Do you mean in the int main function or in the overloading?